Testing Launch AppClip Card before publish to App Store
I am trying to develop app clip for my app and I want to test whole workflow for app clip instead of using local experience.
I have set up the associate domain for my app clip target
applinks:www.example.com
appclips:www.example.com

Also, i have updated my AASA file for adding appclip section
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAMID.com.example.ios",
                "paths": [
                    "/mainapp",
                    "/mainapp/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": [
            "TEAMID.com.example.ios.clip"
        ],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAMID.com.example.ios.clip",
                "paths": [
                    "/appclip",
                    "/appclip/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Finally, I have upload my app with app clip to TestFlight and submitted for review, and passed it, which the state is Pending Developer Release
For now, I think I can test the workflow for app clip, unfortunately, I try to scan the QR code (https://www.example.com/appclip) and redirect to safair, or app clip code which was generated by advanced experience This app is not available on your country or region even i try click on the app clip link provided by apple https://appclip.apple.com/id?p=com.example.ios.clip
Anything I have missed? or I need to publish it to app store so that I can test the whole workflow for app clip?
